# Can JavaFX applications run on Cell Phones?

Tags: mobile, javafx

I have a Java Swing based video game (though more like Java AWT, since most of it is graphics movement of icons), that I would like to port to a Cell Phone.  Android, iOS, or even Windows Phone.

I have read that JavaFX supports this.  Though the posts I read were a few years old.  Does anyone know status of JavaFX on current versions of Android, iOS, or even Windows Phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX requires a JRE to run on. Neither of those three mobile platforms support this natively. So you will need to return to a framework that allows you to do exactly that.

The most positive lead at the moment seems to be the [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/) from the Gluon project. However as far as I am aware, this currently only supports iOS and Android.

Comment: Thanks, that help a lot!

Comment: They also support embedded - but yeah, your answer sums it up pretty well. And btw.: the status of JavaFXPorts is usable. There are performance drawbacks (I have them when rendering `Text` nodes), but most of it runs surprisingly well.